# Link service based on $http to controller

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I am using a service based on $http which on success is updating the $scope.

Also, I want to have the access to the service in my directive, the on ng-click in directive make some POST, and then refresh the data from server and update the scope afterwards. So the route for the signal would be: directive -> service -> controller -> $scope. How can I do that without invoking a method on controller, but invoking it from directive?

I know I can bind some methods between directive and controller, but I have like 8 possible methods and I don't want to write 8 times `method1:"&"` and `<myDirective method1="method1()" method2="method2() "etc...` That would be a mess.

I don't want you to write much code for me, just some hints, please...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not create isolated scope, or set scope=true inside your directive, the directive runs within the scope of controller.

So your options then are to either

- Have the methods on the controller and access them as normal scope methods in the directive.
- Inject the service into directive as you do it in controller and call the service and update the controller scope however you want

Still if you want to make directive reusable, it is better to use isolated scopes.

Comment: Unfornately, I am isolating the scope, that is why the method1:"&", method2:"&", etc.